# How to wrap with enter in textblock?

Tags: xml, wpf

Perhaps the title is a bit 'misleading, for this I apologize. But I would like to understand why my TextBlock does not wrap when I press enter, it is a problem of control? Maybe it does not work well? This is my xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="SF_DebugProject.Information"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Info" Height="400" Width="500">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <Label>dfdfdfd dfdfd</Label>
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
        <Label>
        <TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
            dfdfd diofsidi sdjoif
            dfd this should be wrap...
        </TextBlock>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

and this is a preview of what I told you:

[image]

as you can see the second line of the textblock does not wrap but remains stopped at the first. From what is causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few options when it comes to wrapping text manually in `TextBlock`. You can either use `LineBreak`

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow">
    dfdfd diofsidi sdjoif
    <LineBreak/>
    dfd this should be wrap...
</TextBlock>
```

or set [`xml:space="preserve"`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788746(v=vs.110).aspx) against `TextBlock`, but this will also preserve spaces before each line

```
<TextBlock TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" xml:space="preserve">
    dfdfd diofsidi sdjoif
    dfd this should be wrap...
</TextBlock>
```

3rd option would be to put new line character in `Text`

```
<TextBlock 
    TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow" 
    Text="dfdfd diofsidi sdjoif&#10;dfd this should be wrap..."/>
```